# Como usar ucfirst en un formulario PHP

Tags: php, formularios

¿Cómo se usa **ucfirst** en el "nombre" de un formulario PHP?.
Necesito recibir (sí o sí), los nombres y apellidos con **la primera letra** en mayúscula, y bien sabemos que hoy x hoy aquellos que completan sus datos en un formulario web desde un móvil no siempre "se molestan" en empezar sus nombres y apellidos en capital, y quiero forzarlo desde el propio PHP.
¿Dónde va **ucfirst** (sólo en "nombre")...?

```
<?php

$nombre .= $_POST['nombre'];
$mail .= $_POST['email'];
$asunto .= $_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje .= $_POST['mensaje'];

$header .= 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Enviado por: " . $nombre . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "E-Mail: " . $mail . " \r\n\r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Asunto: " . $asunto . " \r\n\r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "" . $mensaje . " \r\n\r\n";

?>
```

Agredeceré algún ejemplito de código, porque PHP no es lo mío...
:(
==================
==================
**EDITO** (solución)
A quien pueda servirle, guiándome por @Lixus , lo hice así:

```
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Enviado por: " . ucwords($nombre) . " \r\n";
```

Y eso fue todo. Ahora aunque los visitantes al sitio escriban sus nombres en minúsculas (pasa en el +50% de los casos, a pesar de las medidas que se tomen en el desarrollo y programación, porque muchos teclados moviles y tablets ignoran las capitalize automáticas), desde ahora con un simple **ucwords** en $nombre ya estoy recibiendo la información como yo necesitaba.
Y si se quiere forzar más:

```
<input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" class="capitales" required>
```

Y en el CSS:

```
.capitales {text-transform: capitalize}
```

Y automáticamente todo pasa de ésto ==> juan perez a ésto ==> **J**uan **P**erez

Saludos
;)
---------

Comment: No edites la pregunta para establecer una respuesta. En su lugar, responde a tu propia pregunta y si procede, acéptala como respuesta correcta para cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: Esto de puntuar, comentar, editar, que sí, que no, es muy difícil de entender. No veo mal que cualquiera que lee una pregunta se encuentre (luego), con la solución al problema. En fin. Es una opinión.

Answer (score 3):

Tomando tu código original puede ser así:

```
<?php
    $nombre .= $_POST['nombre'];
    $mail .= $_POST['email'];
    $asunto .= $_POST['asunto'];
    $mensaje .= $_POST['mensaje'];

    $header .= 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
    $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

    $cuerpo_mensaje .= "Enviado por: " . ucwords($nombre) . " \r\n";
    $cuerpo_mensaje .= "E-Mail: " . $mail . " \r\n\r\n";
    $cuerpo_mensaje .= "Asunto: " . $asunto . " \r\n\r\n";
    $cuerpo_mensaje .= "" . $mensaje . " \r\n\r\n";
?>
```

Ahora que si `$nombre` tiene tanto el nombre como el apellido juntos, en vez de sacar substrings, te recomiendo lo dividas en `$nombre` `$apellido` para que hagas un `ucfirst()` a ambos, para así asegurarte que tanto nombre como apellido tengan la primer letra en mayúscula.

```
$nombre .= $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido .= $_POST['apellido'];

$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Enviado por: " . ucfirst($nombre) . " " . ucfirst($apellido) . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Muy bien @Lixus (interesante), pero "desgraciadamente" hay un solo input para nombre y apellido...Acabo de ver hace 2 minutos la opción ucwords() que creo seria para poner en mayúscula la primera letra de cada palabra... ¿No? ... Si eres tan amable, ¿cómo seria el código con ucwords()? __Gracias

Comment: Igual, solo cambia `ucfirst` por `ucwords`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$nombre .= $_POST['nombre'];
$mail .= $_POST['email'];
$asunto .= $_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje .= $_POST['mensaje'];

$header .= 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Enviado por: " . ucwords(mb_strtolower($nombre,'UTF-8')) . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "E-Mail: " . $mail . " \r\n\r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Asunto: " . $asunto . " \r\n\r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "" . $mensaje . " \r\n\r\n";

?>
```

Así debería de funcionar.
Saludos.