# ¿Forma correcta de agregar otro javascript a formulario PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Intentando poner en práctica una posible solución a mi [entrada anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64030/como-usar-ucfirst-en-un-formulario-php) me topé con un código que (dicen), funciona para lo que quiero, pero me lío con PHP y no sé cómo agregar otro javascript al formulario php que ya tengo (y tiene un js ya metido).

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.assign("pagina.html");
</script>';
// etc
// etc
?>
```

Y también quiero agregarle éste:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
function capitAll(e){   
    e= window.event? event.srcElement: e.target;
    var str= e.value.toLowerCase();
    var Rx= /\b([a-z]+)\b/ig;
    str= str.replace(Rx,function(w){
        return w.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+w.substring(1);
    });
    return str;
}
</script>
```

Pero no consigo hacer que funcione. El formulario se envía (no hay errores), pero sé algo estoy haciendo mal...
¿Cómo se hace para agregar un nuevo script al php...?
Gracias
----------

Comment: Pues de entrada no te recomiendo que mezcles código del Front-end (Javascript) con código Back-end (Php), Si bien te funciona ahora un parte de tu código JS, después será MUY complicado mantenerlo. Para una solución mas limpia a tu problema lo recomendable es que utilices un WebService.

Comment: OK, ELM Acabo de meterlo (me faltaba eco 'el_script' pero igual no funciona el codigo (aunque viéndolo pareciera que si). En fin, seguiré con mi lucha de solucionar el problema planteado en el primer post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64030/como-usar-ucfirst-en-un-formulario-php --Gracias--

Answer (score 0):

Ok... ¿un archivo PHP es una mezcla de HTML y PHP cierto? (al menos en su forma original)..

No tienes mas que poner el `<script>` de la misma forma que en cualquier otro archivo html, asegurandote de ubicarlo en el lugar correcto o desado (un script puede ir en diferentes lugares) y que produzca un HTML valido.

```
<?php
// haces muchas cosas php

// en algun punto esta tu HTML, incluido o enlinea, pero esta (no me refiero a un servio REST o similar) 
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- aqui tus metas y scripts y links  -->
    <!-- asi agregas el JS, igual que en cualqueir otro html -->
    <script src="/ruta/al/archivo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       // esta es la opción que creo quieres. 
       window.location.assign("pagina.html");
    </script>

    <?  // si quires puedes usar PHP inline, interpolar variables, fors, etc.

    echo '<script src="/ruta/al/archivo.js"></script>';

    ?>
  </head>
  <body> 
   <!-- aqui tu pagina -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valiosa ayuda @Emanuel Ve (sobre todo para los que tocamos PHP de oído), aunque yo decía de meter **un script extra** en un formulario php que ya tenia uno. Ya lo resolví (lo comenté arriba), faltaba agregar un nuevo echo 'el-script' , pero el script no hace lo que promete... Un saludo --

Comment: @Pablo_Web una pagina HTML puede tener tantos `<script>` como quieras. no importa que tenga uno o veinte.

Comment: @Pablo_Web quiza tienes que agrega a la pregunta las partes faltantes (pero escenciales) de ese php.